# Mysql полнотекстовый поиск - игнорировать избранные символы

Tags: mysql, sql

Стоит вопрос с игнорированием всевозможных символов при полнотекстовом поиске. В частности, делаю поиск по товарам. Имена товаров пестрят всякими знаками

- Dell G3 15 3579 G315-7190
- Apple MacBook Pro 13" (2017 год) [MPXQ2]
- Gigabyte H310M S2H (rev. 1.0)

Самое зло тут - это дефисы, тире, скобки и кавычки. Особенно дефисы. Пользователи склонны при поиске пропускать что-то в названии и чаще всего дефисы. Пользователь может написать "G315-7190", или "G315 7190" или "G3157190". И нужно найти товар.

Я придумал делать следующее. Есть поле `name`, где хранится стандартное название продукта. Можно завести поле `additional`, где хранить имя продукта в нескольких вариантах

- Все знаки кроме букв и цифр заменены на пробелы.
- Все знаки кроме букв, цифр и пробелов убраны.

Далее добавить полнотекстовый индекс для этого поля и искать дополнительно ещё и по нему - всегда или в случае, если поиск по `name` ничего не дал.

- Но есть ли возможность как-то настроить полнотекстовый индекс mysql,
  чтобы игнорировать нужные символы (особенно дефис)?
- И что скажете насчёт моей идеи? Может есть какие-то другие варианты?
- Что вообще можно сделать?

Mysql на хостинге 5.5.62-cll-lve